# Facebook share button integration with description ,imgae issue!

Tags: facebook, button, fbml, share

I am facing problem in share button  integration with my website.
When i  click share it is only showing my website url.It is not showing image and description what might be the problem ???

Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome  Facebook Read Eval Log Loop</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Examples for the Facebook Platform.">
    <meta name="keywords" content="facebook, connect, facebook connect, javascript,    examples, javascript sdk, javascript library, library, howto, tutorial, api, facebook apisdk">
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="5526183">
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="123865001025929">
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://fbrell.com/logo.jpg">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://fbrell.com/">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

    <script>
    FB.init({
             appId  : '123865001025929',
             status : true, // check login status
             cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
             xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
    });
    </script>
    <fb:share-button href="http://fbrell.com" type="button"> </fb:share-button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are missing the `og:title` so you need to add it, something like: `<meta property="og:title" content="Welcome  Facebook Read Eval Log Loop"/>`
2. close the tags properly as mentioned by @dwarfy
3. Don't use the `fb:share-button`! use the [Like plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) instead

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work with the facebook linter :

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url=http%3A%2F%2Ffbrell.com%2F

Anyway it's best to always use the linter (in the link above) so that it gives you warnings and errors about your og tags, an ALSO it force facebook to REFRESH its cached information about your page, which in your case was not yet refreshed after you added tags, I suppose, so you were not seeing your last changes ... It's this information Facebook uses when you share something.

Does it work now ?

Btw it gives this :

```
Warning
Required Property Missing   og:title is required
```

Comment: @user746909 did you check the linter link ? Is the information and image correct there ? http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url=http%3A%2F%2Ffbrell.com%2F

Comment: there is error Warning
Required Property Missing   og:title is required how do i solve it

Comment: Something like : `<meta property="og:url" content="Facebook Read Eval Log Loop">` ??? Please try to understand error message when there are

Comment: Also I would close the meta tags : `<meta property="og:url" content="Facebook Read Eval Log Loop" />`  (notice the closing **/** )